# Google URL Shortener history without User Authentication?

Tags: google-authentication, google-oauth, google-url-shortener, goo.gl

I have been reading all over the Internet, but can't find an example of listing my account's history (i.e. the links that I have shortened)  without using OAuth2.0.

So, I was wondering, does anyone know if I can download my history without having to be redirected to authenticate. I was thinking if there is a way in which I can provide my username and password and authentication will be handled automatically without the need for my input.

Any suggestions if that is possible will be appreciated.

Thanks